# AngularJS ng-repeat two elements one row

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

my question is regarding ng-repeat's capabilities. I have a list of objects that i'm using it to iterate over but I want to be able to display two of them in the same row but so far I'm sort of clueless.
Is there a way I can use ng-repeat in a similar way to array indexing in other languages?

```
<div ng-app="sps" ng-controller="peoplecontrol">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Members</h1>
        </div>
        <center><h3>Administration</h3></center>

        <div ng-repeat ='admin in admins'>
            <div ng-if= "$index%2== 0"> 
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <img class= 'img-responsive' src='{{admin.img}}' />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <h4>{{admin.position}}</h4>
                        <p><i>{{admin.description}}</i></p>
                        <p>{{admin.bio}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end of evens-->

                <div ng-if = "$index%2!=0">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src='{{admin.img}}'/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h4>{{admin.position}}</h4>
                            <p><i>{{admin.description}}</i></p>
                            <p>{{admin.bio}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end of odds--> 
                </div><!--end of rows-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you will have to restructure the array into groups before trying to use `ng-repeat`, as the behavior of `ng-repeat` is to create a new row for *every* item in the array.

Comment: This is what i've done. I just made groups of objects left and right and then added an ng-if statement which checks that they have the same index so that it adds correctly and it has worked!